# Is there a .NET 3.5 equivalent of 4.0's AppendAllLines?

Tags: c#, .net, io

```
var output = DataList.Select(x => x.blah blah blah); 
string outputFilePath = @"C:\output.txt";
File.AppendAllLines(outputFilePath, output);
```

My above .NET 4 code was put in a for/next loop that iterates a few times, so appending is necessary (as opposed to overwriting/rewriting).  Now, I've been told I have to use .NET 3.5 instead and AppendAllLines spits out the error 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for AppendAllLines.

Does anyone know of a fix that does not require me to change my existing code too drastically and uses .NET 3.5?

Comment: Write your own method that does the same as AppendAllLines, and has the same signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in the framework exists to do exactly that, using the proper streaming, but you can write your own method easily enough:

```
public static void AppendAllLines(string path, IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        foreach (var line in lines)
            writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is available.

```
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, DataList.Select(x => x.blah blah blah).ToArray());
string outputFilePath = @"C:\output.txt";
File.AppendAllText(outputFilePath, output);
```

Should work, `string.Join` takes a `string` and a `string[]`.

Comment: I prefer `Environment.NewLine` over `"\r\n"`

Comment: This method doesn't stream the processing of the data before writing it to the file; it is forced to bring the entire file's data into memory