# WriteAllLines arguments give an overload error

Tags: c#

I wanted to delete 2 last lines of an text file.

I've found this [how to delete last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264117/c-sharp-how-to-delete-last-line-in-a-text-file) in forum. I get an error of overload of converting string to string[] . After a look I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729199/what-is-the-net-3-5-equivalent-of-writealllines-in-my-code) wich advise to use of array. But both does not work with me ?!

Finally I've wrote that

```
 string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName);
        string [] newlines = new string[lines.Length-2];
        for (int i=0; i<lines.Length - 2; ++i)
            newlines[i] = lines[i];
        File.WriteAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName, newlines);
```

Why when I use those given exemples don't work with me ?
Should I add something ?

I have those as using:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: When I use the code int the links the error is "The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: what is `PublicVariables.AddedFileName`?

Comment: `newlines` is clearly a `string[]`, so what is the type of `PublicVariables.AddedFileName`?

Comment: PublicVariable is a string which contains the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ArrayResize to make things simplier:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName);
Array.Resize(ref lines , lines.Length-2);

File.WriteAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName, lines);
```

Comment: It's better then my for loop

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `PublicVariables.AddedFileName` is of type `string`.

To reduce the possibility of bugs in your code and improve performance for larger files, you can replace your code by this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName);
File.WriteAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName, 
    lines.Take(lines.Length - 2));
```

`lines.Take` uses Linq to enumerate of the array until the second to last element is reached, this makes it possible to not copy the array in memory (and not have it in memory twice).

Comment: Nice Linq solution! :)

Comment: Yes it's a static string. What you wrote exists in the links that I've wrote. But I can't use what you wrote. debugger gives "The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments"  error.

Comment: The trouble begins when I add after lines Take (what I want to use :))

Answer (score 0):

probably  the handle of the file is locked and you are trying to access the some file with different handle try  to change the name of the file when you write for example

```
 File.WriteAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName+"1", newlines);
```

Comment: File.ReadAllLines releases the file handle before it returns.

Comment: in the comments the asker states that he receives a build error.

Comment: The error is in the debugger when I write the code. I did not and can not run it.

Comment: sorry I  did not see that :) I will update my Answer

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted that could cause the error you stated so the problem must lie elsewhere, however, this code should be much faster:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName);
string[] newlines = new string[lines.Length - 2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(lines, 0, newlines, 0, newlines.Length);
File.WriteAllLines(PublicVariables.AddedFileName, newlines);
```

Comment: Sorry this code is working which is not working with me are the codes in the links. This code I've wrote using the links using a part of the codes of links. The aruments as take does not work